# android acces localhost over the internet

Tags: android, localhost

We connected the android device to wifi in order to get access to the localhost server,
but can you please help me in accessing my PC server(localhost of WAMP server) over the internet, not through the wifi network.

What I mean is how do I get access to my pc server from outside my home?

Comment: you should have a public ip to access your PC

Comment: do you mean that I should use the external IP instead of the local IP ?

Comment: Yes exactly an external IP would be useful

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work ... can you please suggest any useful tips to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Real IP and server where You can host your services . Over Internet you can access from your phone via internet. Real IP will me mapped from your android application

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the access in your home router, which has to be connected directly to the Internet - it means the ISP gave you a public IP address. In the router administration you have to set port forwarding (use port no. 80 for HTTP server) to your local IP.